# Italicize subset of text in label of radioGroup

Tags: lightning, css, html5, lightning-radiogroup, radiogroup

I am trying to hightlight part of the text in a radioGroup label.  I can do this in a checkbox component using CSS.

```
<aura:attribute name="registrationOptions" type="List" default="[
    {'label': 'Open Day ($375)', 'value': 'Open Day'},
    {'label': 'Open Day + Biologic workshop ($500)', 'value': 'Open Day + Workshop'},
    {'label': 'Biologic workshop ($200)', 'value': 'Workshop ONLY'}
]"/>
```

For example, I want to italicize just the word Biologic in the radioGroup label.

```
<lightning:radioGroup aura:id="amountDueRadioButton" 
    label=""
    name="registrationOption"
    onchange="{!c.calculateRegistrationAmountDue}"                       
    type="radio"
    options="{! v.registrationOptions }"
/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to achieve needs a bit tweaking :-)

1. Include your *italicised* or other rich text in attribute in escaped form.

   e.g. Bold the amount in this label > `{'label': 'Open Day &lt;b&gt;($375)&lt;/b&gt;', 'value': 'Open Day'}`
2. You would need to use HTML tags `<input>` and `<label>` to display your options (please don't ask that the styling is not as per the lightning experience. You can apply the SLDS styles to suit your needs).

   `<input type="radio" id="terms" name="terms" value="true" />
   <label for="terms"><aura:unescapedHtml value="{!item.label}" />`
3. Use the [`aura:unescapeHtml`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/aura:unescapedHtml) or [`lightning:formattedText`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:formattedText/example) to reformat the richtext and display it properly.

---

> **Your final component will be**

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global">
    <aura:attribute name="registrationOptions" type="List" 
                    default="[
                             {'label': 'Open Day &lt;b&gt;($375)&lt;/b&gt;', 'value': 'Open Day'},
                             {'label': 'Open Day + Biologic workshop ($500)', 'value': 'Open Day + Workshop'},
                             {'label': 'Biologic workshop ($200)', 'value': 'Workshop ONLY'}
                             ]"/>


    <aura:iteration items="{! v.registrationOptions }" var="item">
        <input type="radio" id="terms" name="terms" value="true"  ></input>
        <label for="terms"><lightning:formattedText value="{!item.label}" /></label><br/>
    </aura:iteration>

</aura:component>
```

> **Output**

Radio list in red is your component while in green is from the above answer. Pretty awesome, right! :D

[image]

Comment: The code your provided worked well for displaying italics in a radio button label.  It looks like I need to change the way I was handling a click of an option.  The following function was getting called when I used lightning's radio button.  This doesn't seem to work now.  Thoughts?

    calculateRegistrationAmountDue: function(component, event, helper) {
        var registrationOption = event.getSource().get("v.value");

Comment: @MicheleKleinhomer the question in context here is specific to formatting of subtext with Radio list, which the post answers. Consider accepting this answer if it helped you and if you have further questions please first search and then post a new question if you don't find help from existing questions.

Comment: Lightning formatted right text base component would be a better alternative than using unescaped HTML

Comment: Thanks @Raul. It is indeed better. updated.